# Ropemacs does not work under windows environment

Tags: python, emacs, ropemacs, rope, pymacs

I am trying to use Emacs as my Python IDE under win32. I referred to several posts on the Internet and I had yasinppet, auto-complete, pymacs, ropemacs installed on my Emacs. It shows that Emacs will load python mode, rope mode, yas mode and auto-complete mode after I create a *.py file. But I got an error saying that the system cannot find pymacs.py file when I tried to use functions like "Goto definition" (C-c g) of rope. I am quite sure I have installed pymacs correctly and the path is right. So anyone can help me out of this?

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\Python27\\Pymacs\\Pymacs\\pymacs.py", line 265, in loop
    value = eval(text)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: \'ascii\' codec can\'t decode byte 0xe5 in position 12:
         ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The included error says something about a unicode decoding error. Did you take a look at line 265 in pymacs.py to figure out what's happening there? Are you trying pymacs with a python file which has unicode characters in it? If so then you may want to try a simple python file first which has no unicode characters and if it works with that then you'll know there is some unicode encoding problem somwehere.

Comment: Thanks! I did a bit more searches on Google and I found this problem is an open issue of Pymacs. Here is the thread: https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/issues/7